# type conversion in python from float to int

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change `data_df` which is type `float64` to `int`.

```
data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].astype(int)
```

I get the following error.

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '17.44'

Answer (score 11):

I think you need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) first because `float` cannot be cast to `int`:

```
data_df['grade'] = pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade']).astype(int)
```

Another solution is first cast to `float` and then to `int`:

```
data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'grade':['10','20','17.44']})
print (data_df)
   grade
0     10
1     20
2  17.44

data_df['grade'] = pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade']).astype(int)
print (data_df)
   grade
0     10
1     20
2     17
```

---

```
data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].astype(float).astype(int)
print (data_df)
   grade
0     10
1     20
2     17
```

### ---

If some values cannot be converted and after `to_numeric` get error:

> ValueError: Unable to parse string

is possible add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`.

If `NaN` values then cast to `int` is not possible see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na):

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({'grade':['10','20','17.44', 'aa']})
print (data_df)
   grade
0     10
1     20
2  17.44
3     aa

data_df['grade'] = pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade'], errors='coerce')
print (data_df)
   grade
0  10.00
1  20.00
2  17.44
3    NaN
```

If want change `NaN` to some numeric e.g. `0` use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
data_df['grade'] = pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade'], errors='coerce')
                     .fillna(0)
                     .astype(int)
print (data_df)
   grade
0     10
1     20
2     17
3      0
```

Small advice:

Before using `errors='coerce'` check all rows where is impossible casting to numeric by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (data_df[pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
  grade
3    aa
```

Comment: after trying the first one it gives me an error of ValueError: Unable to parse string

Comment: after adding errors = 'coere' it returns error Cannot convert NA to integer

Comment: i think this solution is overly complex, and does not seem to work well

Comment: @john - in pandas is impossible convert `NaN` to `int`, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na). One possible solution is replace `NaN` to some value e.g. `0` and then cast to `int`.

Comment: @zabeltech - sorry, I first think it is easy, but then it is more complicated. Good luck!

Comment: better would be to actually convert to float to an int that makes sense and not to NaN, like 1.4 > 1

Comment: @zabeltech - yes, but problem is there are some non numeric values, so then cast to numeric and then to int is not possible. So first need remove non numeric to nan and then fill NaN to some values and last convert to int.

Comment: @zabeltech - I try reformat my answer, I think now it is more clear.

Comment: @jezrael fair enough

Answer (score 3):

what works is `data_df['grade'] = int(pd.to_numeric(data_df['grade']))`
The method `as_type(int)` throws and error because it want's to tell you, that no exact conversion from float to integer is possible and you will lose information.
My solution will truncate the integer (i.e. 1.9 will become 1), so you might want to specifiy in your question wether you want to convert float to integer by truncation or by rounding (i.e. 1.9 will become 2)

Comment: what will be the best solution for if then I want to use data_df.hist(x = 'Grade')

Answer (score 2):

From:

```
data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].astype(int)
```

Need to change int into 'int'

```
data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work for me where none of the other earlier answers did the job for me:

`data_df['grade'] = data_df['grade'].apply(np.int)`